# Match a key to value from a dict and replace a value matching another dictionary using ansible

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, json-query

I've a dictionary containing the below items.

```
PID:
  Cisco:
    - A9K-MOD80-TR
    - A9K-RSP440-TR
    - ASR9001-LC
    - SFP-10G-SR
```

The above dictionary I want to match with the list below with the following logic, if "SFP-10G-SR" (or any of the other values exist) exist in any of the part_id below, then replace 'Manufacturer' with Cisco (Cisco in this case is the key in the dict PID).

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'hostname': '-', 'device_id': 287, 'serial': '-', 'Name': '-', 'Manufacturer': '', 'part_id': 'ASR9001-LC'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'hostname': '-', 'device_id': 287, 'serial': '-', 'Name': '-', 'Manufacturer': '', 'part_id': 'SFP-10G-SR'})
```

I've somehow managed to get it to work but it's ugly and it's in a weird format with the below code.

```
  - name: test
    set_fact:
      new_merged_list: "{{new_merged_list}} {{ item|combine({'Manufacturer': PID|dict2items|json_query(query)}) }}"
    loop: "{{ merged_list | flatten(levels=1) }}"
    vars:
      query: "[?contains(value, '{{item.part_id }}')].key"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ new_merged_list }}"
```

It gives me the below output

```
{
    "msg": " 
    {'hostname': '-', 'device_id': 287, 'serial': '-', 'Name': '-', 'Manufacturer': ['Cisco'], 'part_id': 'ASR9001-LC'} 
    {'hostname': '-', 'device_id': 287, 'serial': '-', 'Name': '-', 'Manufacturer': ['Cisco'], 'part_id': 'SFP-10G-SR'} 
}
```

If I run a debug on the "new_merged_list" I'm getting the below message

```
"msg": "AnsibleUnsafeText"
```

What I want is to keep the above as a dictionary, could anyone assist with a better solution or maybe assist in converting this back to a dictionary? In it's current state I'm having issues working with the "new_merged_list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct despite the fact that it might seem ugly and weird. Let's simplify the data, e.g.

```yaml
    PID:
      Cisco: [A, B]
      HP: [C, D]
    merged_list:
        - {Manufacturer: '', part_id: A}
        - {Manufacturer: '', part_id: D}
```

Your code with only a few modifications

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        new_merged_list: "{{ new_merged_list|default([]) +
                             [item|combine({'Manufacturer': manufacturer})] }}"
      loop: "{{ merged_list }}"
      vars:
        _dict: "{{ PID|dict2items }}"
        query: "[?contains(value, '{{ item.part_id }}')].key"
        manufacturer: "{{ _dict|json_query(query)|first }}"
```

gives the new list

```yaml
  new_merged_list:
  - Manufacturer: Cisco
    part_id: A
  - Manufacturer: HP
    part_id: D
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this solution and it worked almost right out of the box, the result is much cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the folowing playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    PID:
      Cisco:
        - A9K-MOD80-TR
        - A9K-RSP440-TR
        - ASR9001-LC
        - SFP-10G-SR
      toto:
        - bla
        - ble
        - bli

    model_brand: >-
      {{
        PID
        | dict2items(key_name='brand', value_name='model_list')
        | selectattr('model_list', 'contains', model | default('none'))
        | map(attribute='brand')
        | default(['Unkown brand'], true)
        | first
      }}

  tasks:
    - name: Show brand for known models (pass as extra param -e model='test')
      debug:
        msg: "Model {{ model | default('none')}} is of brand {{ model_brand }}"
```

Gives

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show brand for known models (pass as extra param -e model='test')] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Model none is of brand Unkown brand"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   



$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e brand='ASR9001-LC'

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show brand for known models (pass as extra param -e model='test')] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Model none is of brand Unkown brand"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   



$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e model='ASR9001-LC'

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show brand for known models (pass as extra param -e model='test')] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Model ASR9001-LC is of brand Cisco"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   



$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e model='ble'

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show brand for known models (pass as extra param -e model='test')] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Model ble is of brand toto"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```